# Extract a list of indices of a scipy.sparse.csr_matrix

Tags: python, scipy

I have a csr matrix A of the form:

```
(0, 6)  0
(0, 8)  0
(0, 15) 1
```

I want to extract only the indices (without the data) as a list but `A[0]` returns the first element.

The result should be a list like:

```
((0,6), (0,8), (0,15))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the [`COO`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.tocoo.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.tocoo)*'rdinates* :

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

A = csr_matrix(([0, 0, 1], ([0, 0, 0], [6, 8, 15])))

coordinates = A.tocoo(); out = tuple(zip(coordinates.row, coordinates.col))
```

Output :

```
print(out)

((0, 6), (0, 8), (0, 15))
```

Answer (score 0):

**With a random 1x15 matrix:**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

random_values = np.random.randint(2, size=(1, 15))
A = csr_matrix(random_values)

print(A)
```

**Get the indexes of all non-zero values:**

```
row_indices, col_indices = A.nonzero()
[(i,j) for i,j in zip(row_indices, col_indices)]
```

Note  that your question does not make much sense, as in your example you are asking for the index of zero values, when most of a sparse matrix will be zero values.

Comment: A `csr` can have 0 value elements, most likely when it's been processed a bit.  `A.to_coo()` gives the data, row, col arrays which are displayed in the `repr(A)`.  `A.nonzero()` takes the added step of removing elements that have 0 value.